# What do embedded systems run

Tags: embedded

I know that Linux is a huge part of the embedded systems thing, but what about things like pacemakers and insulin pumps?

Do they run a custom "distro" on the Linux kernel? How complex is the underlying software?

Comment: Distros are primarily to provide a large variety of application packages for desktop PCs.  Embedded systems rarely use a distro, but rather a custom-built kernel and a small set of application programs to fit in non-volatile storage of small size (e.g. NAND flash).  The devices you mention require unique additional requirements and testing as they are medical devices that sustain life.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Actually, most embedded systems run pre-compiled code. The Linux kernel takes readable commands (such as 'cd ..') and converts them to code to be executed.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this. So, these systems aren't technically a distro as much as they are continually executing code?

Comment: In order for a system to add 2 integers from memory together and store the result in a third location, most programming languages would use something similar to `c:=a+b`. The system would first need to fetch the 2 integers, add them together and then store the result, a minimum of 3 operations (on some systems it is 4 operations). If you want to know more, learn machine code programming (like the PICAXE processors without Basic or C).

Comment: Machine code programming sounds crazy hard and I would not know where to start or what to do with it.

Would learning some x86 ASM help to understand these? Right know I'm learning C and have considered x86

Comment: x86 ASM is machine language coding. PICAXE is a smaller processor than the current x86 processors and uses a different set of machine codes.

Comment: But would learning some x86 help me understand low level machine code and things

Comment: @user341129 yes, because it is low level machine code.

Comment: @user341129 - *"they are continually executing code"* -- A processor, unless it's powered off or sleeping, is always executing machine code (even when it's "idle").  Assembly code is not machine code.  *"embedded systems run **pre-compiled** code"* -- High-level languages have to be compiled into machine code for execution unless you have a rare HLL computer.